# Is this graph planar and regraphing the graph with no crossed ribs?

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

I have tried using Euler's formula in order to prove that this graph is planar.
$$F-E+V=2$$
However, I think I am doing some error while counting the faces and the edges.

Comment: Just move vertices $b$ and $e$ inside triangle $adc$. Also, play this game: http://planarity.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use Euler's formula if you know the graph is planar. You cannot use it to prove it is planar. What would $F$ be unless you already have a planar drawing?

That said, the given graph seems to be planar.

Join $b$ and $d$ by going around $c$ and move $e$ to the top of $a$ and $b$. The two edges between $a$ and $d$ can be drawn close to each other.

Comment: What you can do with Euler's formula is to find what $F$ should be if the graph is planar.  That may help with finding a planar representation.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: True. In fact, perhaps one could even construct puzzles where you can prove that a graph is not planar by finding a contradiction on the value of $F$ as predicted by Euler's formula.

Answer (score 2):

As G Tony Jacobs recommends, here is such a planar multi-graph:

[image]

(No need to "accept" or up-vote this... as it is simply a visualization of Jacobs' solution.)

Comment: Upvotes are not just for rewards, but to give future reader an idea of how good the answer is, as rated by the community. If you want to avoid getting points for an answer, you can check the "community wiki" box in your answer.